When is this operator positive semi-definite?
I have the following operator
$$\Phi(\chi_A)=\int \text{d}\eta\, \text{d}\zeta\,\chi_A(\eta,\zeta)\,e^{i(\eta \hat{P}+\zeta\hat{Q})}.$$
With $\chi_A$ the indicator function associated to a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\hat{P},\hat{Q}$ hermitian operators that satisfy $[\hat{P},\hat{Q}]=-i\hbar$. For which conditions on the set $A$ this operator is positive semi-definite?
$$\textbf{Where am I wrong?}$$
One way of proving if $\Phi(\chi_A)$ is positive semi-definite is just by finding an hermitian operator $A$ such that
$$\Phi(\chi_A)=A^2.$$
In order to do so I can define the following operator
\begin{equation}
    A=\int\, d\mu\, d\nu\, \mathcal{F}_\sigma(\mathcal{\chi_A})(\mu,\nu)\,e^{i(\mu \hat{P}+\nu\hat{Q})}
\end{equation}
with $\mathcal{F}_\sigma$ the symplectic Fourier transform, assuming already that $\chi_A(\eta,\zeta)=\chi_A(-\eta,-\zeta)$. Applied twice we find
\begin{align}
    A^2&=\int\, d\mu_1\, d\nu_1\, d\mu_2\, d\nu_2\,\mathcal{F}_\sigma(\mathcal{\chi_A})(\mu_1,\nu_1)\,\mathcal{F}_\sigma(\mathcal{\chi_A})(\mu_2,\nu_2)\,e^{i(\mu_1 \hat{P}+\nu_1\hat{Q})}\,e^{i(\mu_2 \hat{P}+\nu_2\hat{Q})}\\
    &=\int \,d\mu_1\, d\nu_1\, d\mu_2\, d\nu_2\,\mathcal{F}_\sigma(\mathcal{\chi_A})(\mu_1,\nu_1)\,\mathcal{F}_\sigma(\mathcal{\chi_A})(\mu_2,\nu_2)\,e^{i\hbar(\mu_1\nu_2-\mu_2\nu_1)}\,e^{i((\mu_1+\mu_2) \hat{P}+(\nu_1+\nu_2)\hat{Q})}
\end{align}
Defining the new variables $\gamma=\mu_1+\mu_2$ and $\delta=\nu_1+\nu_2$ we can write
\begin{align}
    A^2&=\int \,d\mu_1 \,d\nu_1 d\gamma\, d\delta\,\mathcal{F}_\sigma(\mathcal{\chi_A})(\mu_1,\nu_1)\,\mathcal{F}_\sigma(\mathcal{\chi_A})(\gamma-\mu_1,\delta-\nu_1)\,e^{i\hbar(\mu_1(\delta-\nu_1)-(\gamma-\mu_1)\nu_1)}\,e^{i(\gamma \hat{P}+\delta\hat{Q})}\\
    &= \int \,d\mu_1\, d\nu_1\, d\gamma\, d\delta\, e^{i\hbar(\mu_1\delta-\nu_1\gamma)}\,e^{i\hbar(-\mu_1\nu_1+\mu_1\nu_1)} \mathcal{F}_\sigma(\mathcal{\chi_A})(\mu_1,\nu_1)\,\mathcal{F}_\sigma(\mathcal{\chi_A})(\gamma-\mu_1,\delta-\nu_1)\,e^{i(\gamma \hat{P}+\delta\hat{Q})}
\end{align}
Notice that the integral over the variables $\mu_1$ and $\nu_1$ is the symplectic fourier transform of a convolution, then by the convolution theorem we conclude:
\begin{align}
    A^2&=\int \, d\gamma\, d\delta\,  \mathcal{\chi_A}\left(\hbar\gamma,\hbar\delta\right)\,e^{i(\gamma \hat{P}+\delta\hat{Q})}
\end{align}
This would imply that for any $\chi_A$ there is an operator $A$ verifying the positive semi-definiteness condition, but that is clearly wrong.

Following your assumptions, the commutator $[\hat P, \hat Q]$ should be skew-adjoint, so cannot be the identity.

Too long for an additional comment. I guess that you can keep the assumption $\hat P, \hat Q$ Hermitian and require
$$
[\hat P, \hat Q]=1/(2πi),
$$
as it is the case with the prototypical example
$
\hat P=D_x=\frac{d}{2πi dx},\quad \hat Q=x.
$
Going on with that example your $\Phi(\chi_A)$ is then (essentially) the Weyl quantization of the Fourier transform of $\chi_A$,
i.e.
$$
\Phi(\chi_A)=\text{Op}(\widehat{\chi_{A'}}),\quad A'=-A,
$$
which means that the distribution-kernel of the operator $\Phi(\chi_A)$ is
$$
k(x,y)=\int \widehat{\chi_{A'}}\bigl(\frac{x+y}2, \xi\bigr)e^{2π i\langle
(x-y),\xi\rangle} d\xi.
$$
Then your question can be reformulated as finding sufficient conditions ensuring the non-negativity of the operator
$\text{Op}(\widehat{\chi_{A'}})$.
Of course we need first that $\text{Op}(\widehat{\chi_{A'}})$ is (formally) selfadjoint,
i.e. that $\widehat{\chi_{A}}$ should be real-valued, which requires that $A$ is symmetric with respect to the origin.
We note then that we have
\begin{multline}
\langle \Phi(\chi_A) u, u\rangle=\iint \widehat{\mathcal W(u,u)}(x,\xi)\chi_{A'}(x,\xi) dx d\xi
=\iint \widehat{\mathcal W(u,u)}(-x,-\xi)\chi_{A}(x,\xi) dxd\xi
\\
=\iint \mathcal A(u,u)(x,\xi)\chi_{A}(x,\xi) dxd\xi,
\end{multline}
where $\mathcal A(u,u)$ is the ambiguity function of $u$, defined as the inverse Fourier transform of the Wigner distribution $\mathcal W(u,u)$, i.e.
$$
\mathcal A(u,u)(x,\xi)=\int u\bigl(z+\frac{x}{2}\bigr)
\bar u\bigl(z-\frac{x}{2}\bigr) e^{2iπ z\cdot \xi} dz.
$$
At this stage, we note also that $\mathcal A(u,u)$ is real-valued whenever $u$ is an even function. If we assume that $A$ is symmetric with respect to the origin and $u$ is an even function, we get
\begin{multline}
\langle \Phi(\chi_A) u, u\rangle
=2^{-n}\iint \mathcal W(u,u)(x/2,-\xi/2)\chi_{A}(x,\xi) dxd\xi
\\
=2^{n}\iint \mathcal W(u,u)(x,\xi)\chi_{A}(2x,-2\xi) dxd\xi.
\end{multline}
To simplify matters we may also assume that $A$ is symmetric with respect to the $x$-axis and we get that,
when the operators are acting on even functions, we have
$$
\Phi(\chi_A)=2^n\text{Op}(\chi_{A/2}).
$$
Of course when $A$ is the band $\mathbb R\times[-a, a]$, it is true that this operator is non-negative, because it is the Fourier multiplier
$$
\mathbf 1(\vert D\vert\le a)=\mathbf 1(\vert D\vert\le a)^2.
$$
On the other hand, $\Phi(\chi_A)$ is not non-negative when $A$ is circle with center at the origin and I would be inclined to say that the non-negativity of the operator $\Phi(\chi_A)$ forces $A$ to be (symplectically equivalent to) the band $\mathbb R\times[-a, a]$.

Thanks, Bazin, actually my problem reduces to prove when $\mathcal{F}(\chi_A)$ is a valid Wigner function. Do you have any idea of any practical criteria to find that?
